# Is there an alternative memory allocator that uses separate swapfile?

Tags: linux, virtual-memory

Is there alternative allocator that can be LD_PRELOADed into a process, overrides "malloc", "calloc", etc. and allocates things using it's own swap files (mmaped to files instead of MAP_ANONYMOUS)?

I hope it will prevent a memory-hungry process from slowing down and thrashing the whole system.

Answer (score 1):

Not that I know of.
I don’t believe it would help, either. Your memory-hungry process will still consume as much RAM as with a traditional arrangement, it will just swap to an unusual location once working set exceeds available memory.